# Applying rules to text files

Tags: python, text-files

My text file looks like this;

```
5,6,7,3,4
6,3,4,7,5
etc
```

How would I make a rule in python which checks each line and sees if:

1. It has 5 numbers per line
2. It contains the following integers ("5,6,7,3,4")

If both rules are true; I would want it to count the number of lines that are true.

So far I have tried:

```
count = 0
file = open('text.txt','r')
for line in file.readlines():
    if "5" and "6" and "7" and "3" and "4" in line:
        count+=1
```

Comment: Where are you checking that each line has 5 numbers?

Comment: @mshsayem I did specify that in the post. Yes

Comment: Then where are you counting the lines which has such properties (1 & 2)? There should be two counting, right? One counts if current line has 5 numbers, another counts desired lines found so far.

Comment: No, if both rules are true, then the count should add one @mshsayem

Comment: Say, one line contains `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`. It has more numbers but it will pass your test.

Comment: Splitting a string and particular substring, see `str.split()`, getting count of items, see `len()`.

Comment: @mshsayem it should be == 5, if it is over or below, it should not be counted

Comment: So, back to my first question, where are you counting _that_ in your code?

Comment: @mshsayem with the variable count and I need help adding 1 to it when the lines are valid in text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
count = 0
required = '3,4,5,6,7'.split(',')
with open('text.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        parts = line.strip().split(',')
        if len(parts) == 5 and all(x in parts for x in required):
            count += 1

print count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code:

```
target = ["3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
count = 0

with open("input.txt") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if sorted(line.strip().split(",")) == target:
            count += 1

print(count)
```

where `input.txt` is:

```
5,6,7,3,4
6,3,4,7,5
blatantly invalid
6,4,3,5,7
3,4,5,6,7
3,8,5,6,7
```

This will have the expected output of

```
4
```

This doesn't explicitly have to check the length, and nor does it perform a slow `in` check for each number. It uses the fact that each number is present, and the length is exactly 5 will be true if and only if the sorted list is equal to `target`, here. It only uses a quick (`n log n`) sort and an even quicker list comparison, in addition to being more concise.

You could achieve the same in an easy, lazy one-line

```
with open("input.txt") as input_file:
    count = sum(1 for line in input_file if sorted(line.strip().split(",")) == target)
```

Comment: Just saw this answer, thanks for your detail, but  I used the first one and it achieved the purpose.